# Check Box and new component, works erratically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Hello I am triying to build a new component with the data of checkbox, in order to do this I have the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import BottomScrollListener from "react-bottom-scroll-listener";
import ThingsQuery from "./../querys/ThingsQuery";
import "./styles/Things.scss";

export default class Things extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.displayData = [this.createPag()];
  }

  state = {
    sort: "popular",
    page: 1,
    featured: false,
    allPages: false,
  };

  createPag = (onNull = () => {}) => {
    return (
      <ThingsQuery
        page={this.state.page}
        sort={this.state.sort}
        featured={this.state.featured}
        onNull={onNull}
      />
    );
  };

  handleSortClick = (e) => {
    const sort = e.target.innerText.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.setState({ sort, page: 1, allPages: false }, () => {
      this.displayData = [this.createPag()];
    });
  };

  changePage = () => {
    if (!this.state.allPages) {
      const currentPage = this.state.page + 1;
      this.setState({ page: currentPage });
      const page = this.createPag(() => {
        this.setState({ allPages: true });
      });
      if (!this.state.allPages) {
        this.displayData.push(page);
      }
    }
  };

  handleChangeFeatured = (e) => {
    const featured = e.target.checked;
    console.log("onChangeFeatured");
    console.log(featured);
    this.setState({ page: 1, allPages: false, featured: featured }, () => {
      console.log("State changed");
      this.displayData = [this.createPag()];
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="things col-xs-1 text-center">
        <BottomScrollListener onBottom={this.changePage} />
        <div>
          <div className="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChangeFeatured}
              type="checkbox"
              className="custom-control-input"
              id="customSwitch1"
              checked={this.state.featured}
            />
            <label className="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">
              Featured
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
            <button
              onClick={this.handleSortClick}
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-secondary"
            >
              Popular
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={this.handleSortClick}
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-secondary"
            >
              Newest
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={this.handleSortClick}
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-secondary"
            >
              Latest
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="card-columns">{this.displayData}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have a checkBox, and its checked value is got by state.featured.

This loads correctly If I put in the code `featured=True`, loads that, and if I put false works too.

The problem is when try to change the value on the browser.

When I do click on the switch, this change, and the values change too, and `createPag`, is executed completely, but `<ThingsQuery .... />` doesn't work at the first click, I need to change the checked value 2 times, and of course, after this, I get the opposite data, that I want.

How can I solve this, why `<ThingsQuery.../>`, doesn't run at the first click?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Values that are stored as local instance variables, i.e. `this.displayData` don't cause re-renders when they are changed. They have to be in state, and changed via `setState` for their change to trigger a re-render.

So in your case, you call `setState` to change `sort` and `allPages`, then *after* that state change and the subsequent re-render, you change `this.displayData`, in the `setState` callback. Since the re-render is already done, and changing local instance variables doesn't cause a re-render, nothing changes until it next runs and the `setState` calls a re-render with that new `displayData`.

If you want changes in `this.displayData` to cause a re-render, it should be in state. *Any* value that is affecting what gets rendered should be in state.